# Importing and viewing polygon layer on map?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, mit-app-inventor

How is it possible to import and view a polygon layer (I have it in a shapefile) on a map inside MIT App Inventor? Maybe with LoadFromURL method, but in this case which file I should paste associated with the URL?

Usuful resources I found are:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data
- https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml
- https://puravidaapps.com/geolocation.php

I don't know much about GeoJSON or JavaScript API, so: now that I have a map in the app, how should I proceed?

[image: App screen with map and polygons created manually]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I exported the shp in GeoJSON, I took polylines' coordinates inside notepad and saved them in another txt file; then I imported in matlab the rows where I fliped all long/lat point coordinates and save in another txt file, so I could copy and paste a linestring such as:

[[44.26260443366192, 7.665320437787832],[44.262391856609895, 7.664849184556104],...]

inside the polygone.PointsFromString.

[image: map with desired polylines]

Comment: Please, accept your answer as a valid answer in case if it reconciled your issue

Comment: The app doesn't let me until tomorrow